# Can I deploy & Use SSIS SQL server DTS DLL's onto a machine that does not have SQL server 2008 installed?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Greets.
I've developed some SSIS packages that I want to load up and execute in C# code. The C# code is deployed on our application machine. 
I've referenced the SQLServer.ManagedDTS DLL in my C# project.

I tried gac'ing that DLL on our staging application box, which incidentally also seemed to require gac'ing the SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap DLL as well.

The code to execute the package is like so

```
Runtime.Package package = new Runtime.Application().LoadPackage(ssisPackageFilePath, null);
package.Variables["FilePath"].Value = sourceFilePath;
//Excute Package to insert data from source csv file into a SQL table
Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
```

When I try to run the process I get the following error

```
An Integration Services class cannot be found. 
Make sure that Integration Services is correctly installed on the computer that is running the application. 
Also, make sure that the 64-bit version of Integration Services is installed if you are running a 64-bit application
```

I figured I should be able to simply gac (Install) the one DLL I used to develop the code that executes an SSIS dtsx package file.

I developed the package in a Visual studio 2008 BIDS project which results in a dtsx file.
I referenced the SqlServer.ManagedDTS DLL in a visual studio 2010 project to execute the dtsx file from code.
Tested and debugged locally with success.

What do I need to do to setup my application box in order for my code to be able to execute an SSIS package?

I'm hoping I'm not limited to only being able to execute packages from code on a box that has an instance of SQL server or IntegrationServices installed; which may mean the need for another license.

Do I need to install Integration Services on my app box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install Integration Services to run the package on a server. Just deploying DLLs into GAC won't help in executing a package.

Here is the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx) that describes about `Running an SSIS Package Programmatically on a Remote Computer`.

You need to have at least one server with Integration Services installed to be able to do what the MSDN article describes.

Comment: which requires a separate license

Comment: Correct. Deploying SSIS on any box REQUIRES specific licenses. You MAY be able to get away with just putting on a few CALs if only a few people are running this. Otherwise, think Standard Edition (which can be a few $Thousand). 
Reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/andrew/archive/2009/02/03/licensing-and-scaling-up-sql-server-bi.aspx