# Need to run SSIS via a remote application

Tags: ssis

I'm running into this issue basically:
[Can I deploy & Use SSIS SQL server DTS DLL's onto a machine that does not have SQL server 2008 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751774/can-i-deploy-use-ssis-sql-server-dts-dlls-onto-a-machine-that-does-not-have-s)

Since it's been answered I don't know if my request for further information will get any traction.

I'm running into the same problem I think.  When I deploy locally on my dev box, my application calling SSIS works fine.  When I deploy my application on Server A, and my SSIS package on Server B (my database server), I get the error mentioned in the post: " An Integration Services class cannot be found. Make sure that Integration Services is correctly installed on the computer that is running the application. Also, make sure that the 64-bit version of Integration Services is installed if you are running a 64-bit application".

If I understand things correctly I need to have an SSIS license on my application Server and my database server?

This doesn't seem to make sense.  When you make a SQL call to SQL server, provided you have an enterprise license you only pay once.  You don't have to pay for an extra license for your application server.

I just want to make sure I've got this clear before I go to the higher ups, and that my problem isn't stemming from something else.  So to put it concisely:  **Do you need to have an SSIS license for both your app server and your SQL Server when calling an SSIS package remotely?**

Just to clarify the 64 vs 32 bit thing:  I've got 64 bit OS's running on my local machine, the app server and the database server - and all my VS projects are being built to use "Any CPU".

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I thought I should be thorough on this.

Comment: You are installing part of SQL Server on your application server, why *wouldn't* it consume a license? Rephrase your question "I only installed Excel, not Word, PowerPoint and Access, why should that take an Office license?" Just because it's not the core engine doesn't mean it's not a licensed product. That said, depending on what you're doing, perhaps there is a way to restructure your application to talk to the database server and invoke your packages. Without knowing more though, we can't say. Talk to your LAR if you want another opinion on the licensing aspect

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have SSIS licensed (SQL Server) on any machine that is using SSIS to execute packages.

Comment: This is how I'm calling the package.  pkgLocation is on the database server, which is licensed:

    Application app = new Application();
    Package pkg = app.LoadPackage( pkgLocation, null, false );
    pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
 
If I execute a SQL query remotely to the same server it works fine, so the same logic should apply, should it not?

Comment: I wouldn't think the location of the packages matters.  The machine the software (integration services) is installed on is what needs to be licensed.